# writing to memory mapped file while it is memory-mapped

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have memory mapped a file on disk as follow:

```
 const wchar_t fileName[] = L"temp.txt";
 HANDLE h = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
 HANDLE fileMap = CreateFileMapping(h, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0x0, 1024, NULL);
 char *ptr = (char *)MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 1024)
```

Is it possible to write to the same file by another process while it is memory mapped?

`FILE *fp = fopen("temp.txt", "w+");
 if(NULL == fp) printf("Failed to open\n");`

Above code always prints 'Failed to open' if the file is memory mapped.

Comment: I don't like the way you are mixing different APIs... Anyway, take a look at documentation of the third parameter of `CreateFile`...

Comment: do you mean fopen and createfilemapping? I am trying to simulate the usecase

Comment: Don't files generally get opened (for writing) in exclusive mode, thereby preventing other applications from writing to them?

Comment: possible of course

Comment: @NicolBolas: `CreateFile` takes both an open mode as well as a share mode. You can open a file for writing, and still share it with other writers.

Comment: using "w+" with fopen will try to re-create the file ! Try "r+".

Answer (score 0):

The answer for a coherent shared use is simply :yes ,except for **remote** files. (see documentations of `CreateFileMapping` and/or `MapViewOfFile`).

For shared use you must however open the file (`CreateFile`) in a shared-mode (which you didn't specify).
I don't know in which share-mode `fopen` operates ,but I suspect your `fopen` fails because of the missing share-mode with `CreateFile`. If `fopen` still fails when using a shared-mode you should use `CreateFile` instead,

Comment: I tried with changing the 3rd parameter of `CreateFiile` with `FILE_SHARED_WRITE` and now able to open file in write mode within the same process. But it is now allowed to open the same by another process.

Comment: @user413201: replace "w+" with "r+" with fopen !

Comment: So I assume with "w+" it will never succeed because file is already memory-mapped. Is it the case?

Comment: @user413201: yes. The point is if the file is already opened (by anything) then it's invalid to re-create it ("w+") since this involves a delete and a create. It's possible to delete a file in use but it won't be deleted until the last handle to file (by any process) is closed.

Comment: @engf-010: "w+" is a *truncate* if it already exists, not a delete and create.

Comment: @cdarke: I think you're right. Haven't used the function for decades! However ,that not quite true ,I just don't remember the last time !

Comment: MSDN for fopen with "w+" says : opens an empty file for both reading and writing ,If the file exist ,its contents are destroyed. So this could also mean what I said before.

Comment: @engf-010: since truncation is one Win32 API call, whereas deleting it and creating it again is a lot more work (copying the security info, for example), plus there's a chance another process could grab it, it wouldn't make sense to do it as you say.  The UNIX compilers specifically use the word "truncate", and I admit that Microsoft do things their own way ....